# How to deal with transparent listview in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created four tabs using tabhost, and placed four listviews in each like below:

```
public class prem extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    String[] names = new String[] { "Pr"};


    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, names));
}
```

Problem is I have created background images for each listview but when I scroll the listview goes black.I know that I should add `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`
to the xml file to make the listview transparent, so I have created a new xml and id 
and tried to add `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` in the xml to make transparent, but it just force closes;

`this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, R.id.listb, names));`

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="30px"></TextView>
     <ListView android:id="@+id/listb" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exception is thrown when the app force closes?

Comment: 10-21 14:24:39.451: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add setCacheColorHint(00000000) in the prem java file?

```
ListView lv = getListView();    
lv.setCacheColorHint(00000000);    
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, names));
```

Comment: I edited my comment to match the code from your post. Try replacing this.setListAdapter(...) with what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, I now need to figure out how to add different backgrounds to each of the four listviews.  Thanks your a star

Answer (score 1):

`android:cacheColorHint=#00000000` should do the trick. Where in your layout XML did you put it? It should go in `ListView`, for example:

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Problem is I have originally used a listview tutorial not a custom view so I cannot seem to add a listview element:

Comment: What does that even mean? You said your layout was in XML (main.xml, most likely). Your ListView already exists, just place the cacheColorHint inside the ListView you've already defined.

Comment: The listview was originally default and used the default list in android, it is pointing to the main xml but it is not identified by a id, so I cannot add it to a list view element, when I create a xml with a list view id and specify that in the code it force closes if I add it to the main xml it force closes. I think I might have to create a new custom list view to get this to work the way I need it too.

Comment: No, you don't need to make a custom ListView. Edit your original post to include your XML file, because what you're saying isn't really making sense.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Developers' blog had a post about that a while ago.  According to their post "[Why is my list black? An Android optimization](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)", all you need to do is add the `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` attribute to the `ListView` element.